# Import Android Project created from terminal

Tags: android, eclipse

I created an Android project from terminal because when I create it inside Eclipse there's a problem with the R.java file, which is not created. I think I bypassed the problem creating the project from terminal. I want to know if there's a way to import it in Eclipse and work with it as a normal Android project created inside the IDE. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse to File -> import 
select android--> existing code into workspace
find the root folder of that project, select
then check the project
and follow the steps.
It will be imported to Eclipse.

Comment: When I try to import the project I set the folder created (es. MyFirstApp) as root folder. But it says me that no projects are found to import.

Comment: After choosing the root folder, in the next window. You need to check the project you want to import. or do Projects->Select All.Then remember to UNCHECK both "Copy projects into workspace" and "Add project to working sets"

Comment: But there's nothing to select xD